# how to add users to firebase Authentication using google sheet

Tags: flutter, email, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I added users to cloud firestore using google sheet. How I can add those user emails to firebase authentication without manual entering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the sheet as a CSV and then [import the users into Firebase using its command line interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth). You'll just have to make sure that the columns and values match the [file format](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#file_format) specified there.